# PHP how to split a for loop? Improve performance of a for loop

Tags: php, sql, performance, for-loop

I want to split a for loop in order to increase the performance of the for loop but I don't know what exactly is loop splitting even after some research.

For example,this for loop will run through 100000 accounts and save details to database but I only can get approximately 3xxxx accounts data then the system will stop responding. How can I improve the performance of this for loop to run through huge data?

**My code**

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100000; $i++){
    $url="https://8iportal.com/api/v1/portfolios/$i";
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if(curl_error($curl)){
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($curl);
    }else{
        echo nl2br($result."\n");
    }

    $data = json_decode($result, true); 
    if(isset($data['portfolio_info'])){
            $id= $data['portfolio_info']['id'];
            $user_id = $data['portfolio_info']['user_id'];
            $name = $data['portfolio_info']['name'];  
            $sql="INSERT into portfolio(portfolio_id, user_id,name) values(?,?,?)";
            $query=$conn->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param("iis",$id,$user_id,$name);
            $query->execute();  
            echo nl2br("Account ID : $i , $name have been saved \n");
        }
```

**What I tried**

```
 $sql="INSERT into portfolio(portfolio_id, user_id,name) values(?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?)";
            $query=$conn->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param("iisiisiis",$id,$user_id,$name,$id,$user_id,$name,$id,$user_id,$name);
```

Will this make the insert statement insert 3 accounts details at one time?

Comment: First of all curl hit in loop is really not recommended at all. try to read API documentation and find out that they have any API, which will give bunch of data in a single hit (means to say more than one portfolio at a time).use that one. It will reduce loops.

Answer (score 0):

It will make 3 inserts at the same time and with same data as well since the varible names are same.